# How to make bash to know | is a pipe and not a string

Tags: linux, bash

Hi my question is simple. I want to do this in a command prompt.

```
var="ls | cat"
$var
```

Now I know that when I try to do this manually

```
ls | cat
```

Bash takes | as a special thing. I don't know how its called, I know | it's called a pipe but I mean that bash takes | as a ... and actually makes a pipe. I also figured that when I try to do $var bash actually takes | as a string and not as a pipe.  Well, my question is How can I make bash to realize that | is actually a pipe and not a string. Thanks, I hope I am clear about my point.

Comment: Given the range of answers you're getting, please clarify the use case: Why store the command in a variable? Is an alias the better choice? A shell function?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: use `eval`:

```
var="ls | cat"
eval $var
```

bash interprets the arguments to `eval` as if you had typed that on the command line.

Of course, keep in mind the security risks to using `eval` with user input, in case that's an issue for your program.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not apply - but it sounds like you may be looking for the `alias` command.  You can do `alias var="ls | cat"` and then in your command prompt you can do `var` and it treats it as if you wrote `ls | cat`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to embed executable code into a variable (which should be used to hold data, not code), use a shell function, which is intended to hold code:

```
my_func () {
    ls | cat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is called a pipe, I haven't heard any other naming. Basically the stream output by the command on its left goes as the input to the command on its right. In your case, `ls` output goes into a stream (i.e. a temporary file), and that stream is fed to `cat`. `cat` prints the content of a file, and `ls` stream is very much like a file.

Now, you are trying to make `bash` interpret your variable `var`. To do this, try:

```
var=`ls | cat`
$var
```

On my computer I get this:

```
-bash: Applications: command not found
```

Because in my case, `$var` is expanded to `Applications Documents Downloads`, the output of my `ls`.
Given crudely as is, bash believes this is a command I want him to execute.
If your intention is not to execute `$var`content but print it, try:

```
var=`ls | cat`
echo $var
```

Answer (score 0):

The [cat](/questions/tagged/cat) is not needed here, just use `ls -1` and as other answers say you can alias it or put it in a function.

For example, if you want to override [ls](/questions/tagged/ls) to print each file on a new line do something like

```
> alias ls='command ls -1'
> ls 
file1
file2
etc...
```

And put it in a bash init file like `~/.bashrc` if you want to make the change permanent

Comment: ls | cat was not a real example. Is just an easy enough example that I used, the real problem I wanted to figure out was the pipe inside a variable.  I can do it with special operators like $ but not with pipe and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Functions are suitable for such tasks:**

```
func (){
ls | cat
}
```

Invoke it by saying `func`

**2) Also another suitable solution could be `eval`:**

eval takes a string as its argument, and evaluates it as if you'd typed that string on a command line. (If you pass several arguments, they are first joined with spaces between them.)

```
var="ls | cat"
eval $var
```